# Node.js & Electron: Where to require several modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Requiring 5-10 modules in a javascript file (eg. `app.js`) in a html file/render process window takes about 5 seconds to render that window, although the window is already visible. These required modules are needed for other windows as well, which seems slow. I understand that `require` is also synchronous.

Therefore, should I:

1. [make this asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529152/nodejs-electron-async-multiple-required-files), or
2. require these modules globally for current and new windows, or
3. call these via `ipc` from `main.js` if this is faster?, or
4. make this faster more practically some other way?